# How we can Filter the Insight data for multiple specific campaigns in Facebook marketing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get Insight of an Ad-Account by filtering using multiple specific campaigns, I was able to filter with single specific campaigns
Here is the code which I tried for single specific campaigns

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/insights?fields=actions,reach,impressions,clicks,cpc,spend&filtering=[{field: "campaign.id",operator:"CONTAIN", value: '123456789'}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. You can build a list of campaigns by your specific condition and then you use `IN` operator instead of `CONTAIN` operator like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/insights?fields=actions,reach,impressions,clicks,cpc,spend&filtering=[{field: "campaign.id",operator:"IN", value: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']}]
```

2. You can try to use batch request like this (documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices#-------------------------------------------------------------) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/asyncrequests#adinsights)):

```
curl \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
-F 'batch=[ \
  { \
    "method": "GET", \
    "relative_url": "v12.0/act_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/insights?fields=impressions,spend,ad_id,adset_id&filtering=[{field: "campaign.id",operator:"CONTAIN", value: '123456789'}]" \
  }, \
  { \
    "method": "GET", \
    "relative_url": "v12.0/act_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/insights?fields=impressions,spend,ad_id,adset_id&filtering=[{field: "campaign.id",operator:"CONTAIN", value: '222222222'}]" \
  }, \
]' \
'https://graph.facebook.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I tried both options , option 1 is giving blank response where as option 2 is giving error "(#100) Filter field id not supported in advanced filters."

Comment: @Ash18 I tried first option and it works for me. Are you sure that you use correct campaign ids in your request? Or maybe you don't have insights for given period, you can try add `date_preset=maximum` parameter to your request then to see insights for whole period.

Comment: Tambovstev ,Thanks a lot, Option 1 worked for me I was doing a silly mistake I was checking for PAUSED status campaign